splitting of tangent space over normal and tangent bundle
I want a proof or reference to the following theorem :

If $\Gamma$ is a closed nontrivial simple geodesic in a Riemannian
$N$-manifold $M$, then given $\xi\in\Gamma$ there is a natural splitting
$T_\xi M=T_\xi\Gamma\oplus N_\xi\Gamma$ into the tangent and normal
bundle over $\Gamma$.

By definition it is clear that $T_\xi\Gamma\,\cap\,N_\xi\Gamma=\{\xi\}$. Also taking an arbitrary vector field $X\in T_\xi M$ we could write $$X=X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$ where $X^i$ are components of $X$ and $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^N$ are local coordinates. It is now sufficient to prove the statement that there exist $1<n<N$ such that $$X=\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^nX^i\partial_i}_{\in\,T_\xi\Gamma}\,+\,\underbrace{\sum_{i=n+1}^NX^i\partial_i}_{\in\,N_\xi\Gamma}$$ But I don't see a way to prove $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nX^i\partial_i\in\ T_\xi\Gamma$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{i=n+1}^NX^i\partial_i\in N_\xi\Gamma$. Any help is appreciated.

It is just linear algebra, you should forget about manifolds and think about a 1-dimensional linear subspace in $\mathbb R^n$.

The statement is also not related to the fact that $\Gamma$ is a geodesic, any regularly  parametrized smooth curve would do.
